# to write a binary search program using threads

Tags: java

can we use write a program in java for binary search using threads.
one thread for dividing the array and one for sorting the array.

Comment: @R S: do you want to search or sort?  If you want some O(n log n) parallelized sort using threads then, yes, it can be done and it yelds amazing performances boost compared to mono-threaded sort on modern hardware (16 cores Mac here).  But a binary search cannot be parallelized AFAIK.

Comment: I would be interested to learn of any real-world situation whereby the expense of thread creation and inter-thread communication was actually less than the system time of performing the binary search.

Comment: @PP - when the search space is sufficiently large and the system has multiple processors.

Comment: As food for thought, a good question. Practically speaking, will only contribute to code smell. Good question, because if we try to generalize this to B-Trees and family, you would see some benefit in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing the array consists only of picking the midpoint.  Why do you need a separate thread for this?

Also, you should not be sorting the array in binary search - a prerequisite is that you have a sorted array.

Do you mean to ask about parallelizing a sorting algorithm?  If so, algorithms like mergesort and quicksort can be parallelized because they use the divide-and-conquer paradigm, but since the same kinds of operations are performed on each half, you should be aware that parallelizing will only benefit you if you are working on a system with multiple cores.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Assuming the array is sorted, notionally split the array into as many parts as you have threads and have each thread perform a binary search on each part.

Comment: I haven't done out the math on this but it seems that division and mid point selection on multiple arrays would be slower then just performing the binary search on the larger array.  Would still be classified as n log n though.

Comment: @decompiler There are no multiple arrays - just the one. You specify the begin and end of each part using pointers. That can be done pretty efficiently. However, I don't guarantee that it is any faster - I was just answering the question - "can you use multiple threads".

Comment: Won't help, as most of the threads would end up doing nothing but end up traversing unwanted paths. The height of the tree grows in a logn fashion but the width grows in 2^n fashion.

Comment: Yes, I think that this is a misleading answer.  It is possible in the sense that it will terminate and provide the correct answer, but it unnecessarily worsens the time complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: @decompiled - binary search should be log n, not n log n.

Comment: @danben Thinking about it, all  but one of the threads will immediately stop, as the thing being searched for will not be in their block.
Consider the case where blocksize is 1 and no. of threads == no. of blocks. all threads will perform a only single comparison and one will succeed. This seems quite efficient, given sufficient CPUs to run the threads on. But of course partitioning & thread creation are not free.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: this is correct, but I'm skeptical of the benefits.  It seems that the partitioning step could do no better than the successive bisections of the array in the serial case.  That is to say, by the time partitioning is done, the serial algorithm should have already narrowed the space down to its final "block".

Comment: @danben Of course, the search is log n, the sort is n.  Unless your lucky enough to get your data sorted! (Never seems to be the case.)

Comment: @decompiled: Binary search does not involve a sort.  It has a precondition that the data is sorted.  You cannot factor sorting time into the complexity of binary search, regardless of some business case.