# Concurrent binary chop algorithm

Tags: concurrency, binary-search

Is there a way (or is it even theoretically possible) to implement a binary search algorithm concurrently? I'm guessing the answer may well be no for two reasons:

- Despite lots of Googling I haven't found a concurrent implementation anywhere
- Each iterative cycle of the binary chop depends on the values from the previous one, so even if each iteration was a separate thread it would have to block until the previous one completed, making it sequential.

However, I'd like some clarification on this front (and if it is possible, any links or examples?)

Comment: Similar question: [to write a binary search program using threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237938/to-write-a-binary-search-program-using-threads)

Comment: Sorry for my answer, I didn't want to say that there is any harm in checking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, it looks like binary search is completely nonparallel. But notice that there are only three possible outcomes:

- You hit the element
- The element searched for is before the element you hit
- The element is after

So we start three parallel processes:

- Hit the element
- Assume the element is before, search here
- Assume the element is after, search there

As soon as we know the result from the first of these, we can kill the one which is not going to find the element. But at the same time, the process that searched in the right spot, has doubled the search rate, that is current speedup is 2 out of a possible 3.

Naturally, this approach can be generalized if you have more than 3 cores at your disposal. An important aside is that this way of thinking is what is done inside hardware. Look up carry-lookahead adders for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can figure the answer! To parallelize, there must be some work that can be divided. In case of the bin-search, there is nothing that could possibly be divided and parallelized. bin-search gets into the middle of an array of values. This work cannot be divided. Etc.. until it find the solution.

What in your opinion could be parallelized?

Comment: It's not really my opinion at all... I've stated that from my research I don't think it is possible, I was just after clarification that it wasn't. I think we've all come across situations in the past where we assumed something wasn't possible and then was shocked to find out that it was for whatever reason, I see no harm in checking this in case it's one of those moments!

Comment: You can optimistically start processes up and mux them afterwards. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have n worker threads, you can split the array in n segments and run n binary searches concurrently, combining the results when they are ready. Apart from this cheap trick, I can see no obvious way to introduce parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try a not-quite-binary search, essentially if you have n cores then you can split the array into n+1 pieces. From there you search each of the "cut-points" and see whether the value is larger or smaller than the cut point, this results in you having a fifth of the original search space as opposed to half, as you will be able to select a smaller section.